# Parse.com Query Pointer Value

Tags: php, oop, object, parse-platform

I'm having a problem getting the values from a pointer column. There is a column named "User" that points to the "_User" class in parse. I'm attempting to get the username associated with each row in my locations database. But for some reason, I'm getting a strange response.

```
Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

My code is:

```
$query = new ParseQuery("SignoutDestination");
   $query->includeKey("User");
   // Limit what could be a lot of points.
   $query->limit(100);
   // Final array of objects
   $signoutdestinations = $query->find();

   foreach($signoutdestinations as $obj){
     echo $obj->get("User")->get("username");
   }
```

Has there been a change in the SDK or anything that could be causing this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Maybe its because I don't speak PHP, but the thing that looks wrong to me is the assignment of the find() result.  In the other SDK, find will run asynchronously, so anything you check related to $signoutdestinations won't be initialized.

Comment: No, that's not it. I can do echo $obj->get("User"); and it returns the array of objects fine, but for some reason I can't access the username.

Comment: Another fact from the other sdks, hopefully useful to you, is that username has its own accessor method (called username), not like other attributes where you would use get.

Comment: I wonder which `get()` it is... Is `$obj` actually an object? I'd `var_dump($obj)` or `gettype($obj)` to see. If it is, the call `$obj->get('User')` might not be returning an object. I'd try to debug by deduction there.

Comment: @JakeOls - you mentioned that `$obj->get('User')` returns an array of objects. If so, you'll have to iterate over that result set and call `->get('username')` on each object. `array` is not an object and does not have a `get()` method, or any method for that matter.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely an object. Also, I'm not trying to access the current user, I'm trying to access the associated username for a separate class.

Comment: Actually, not entirely sure what it returns. echo gettype($obj); returns "objectobjectobject..."etc, when I try to access username like an array with $value->User['username'], I get "Cannot use object of type Parse\ParseUser as array"

Comment: Okay, so `$obj` is an object, which is good. I don't know anything about Parse but I am looking at the [source on GitHub](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseQuery.php#L349), and I presume these are all `ParseObject` instances. which [does have a get() method](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseObject.php#L203). You are calling this method, and since it is not throwing an `\Exception` it is either returning the contents of `$this->estimatedData` which appears to be 1/2

Comment: 2/2 [initialised as an array](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/blob/master/src/Parse/ParseObject.php#L705). Or it's returning `null` at the bottom of the method. So if the result of `$obj->get('User')` is not null, then it is an array. Presumably of user objects. So you'll need to iterate over these to call `get('username')` on each, with a nested `foreach`.

Comment: I was looking at this (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-php-sdk/issues/94) , as it's exactly what I need but it's not working..

Comment: Bst thing to do is figure out what you are dealing with - we need to know what `$obj->get('User')` returns, so add this to your loop: `var_dump($obj->get('User'))` or even `gettype($obj->get('User'))`. You basically want to figure out if it's `null`, an `array` or an `object` - and if it's an object, what type of object. If you are sure you are dealing with an object you can get an its name without a `var_dump` with `echo get_class($obj->get('User'));`.

Comment: Added gettype($obj->get('User')) , and it returned NULLNULLNULLNULLNULLobjectobjectobjectobjectobjectobject...

Comment: Not entirely sure what this means..

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue and I kinda find a solution :

```
   $query = new ParseQuery("SignoutDestination");
   $query->includeKey("User"); // I didn't use it in my query
   // Limit what could be a lot of points.
   $query->limit(100);
   // Final array of objects
   $signoutdestinations = $query->find();

   foreach($signoutdestinations as $obj){
     $pointer = $obj->get("User");
     // It retrieves a pointer to object, so you
     // can only getObjectId() and specific fields
     // like this
     $pointer->fetch();
     $pointer->getUsername();
     // Now you're able to getUsername()
   }
```

I hope it will help you, I would have post it as comment but couldn't due to my freshly created account.

EDIT: I changed the code with something I tried on my Parse and it worked, but it just ruins your requests ratio because of fetching, find a clever way to get Username just by querying _User and comparing ObjectId.

Indeed, with the includeKey() it should work as you written it up...

Comment: Thanks, I had to do this when getting the lat/long from a Parse Geopoint, but for some reason it still says "Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object"... I opened an issue on github, but it was quickly closed :/ I'll update this thread in case I find a solution.